# WMS Pop Up not working....?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo, internet-explorer

I have created a web based GIS using Geoserver-Postgis-Openlayers...

Every thing was working fine till I changed the server path from 'Testing to LIVE.'

WMS POP up Function has stopped working in LIVE Server Environment & showing the following error message..

> "Message: Access is denied.
>
> Line: 177 ; Char: 9 ; Code: 0 ; URI:
>   ....../geoserver/OpenLayers-2.8/lib/OpenLayers/Request/XMLHttpRequest.js
>   "

WMS Pop Up code is as follows (Working perfectly at my Test Server)

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: '..../geoserver/LT_WEB/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "", 
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        event.text,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

SERVER - Microsoft Windows 2003 R2.
Web Browser - Internet Explorer 8.0.

In both Servers (Testing & LIVE) GeoServer, PostGIS and OpenLayers 2.8 installed and all paths verified.

Awaiting for your valued response.

Comment: is your Geoserver, and the web server containing your HTML/JS files on the same server and same port number?

Comment: Geoserver-Postgis is installed separately at both servers (Testing & Live)...I copied all my programm files(html / JS /php) from Test to LIVE Server & changed the necessary URL & URI...

Comment: I think your web server is on a different port than your geoserver. Can you tell us what is the complete address of your geoserver (along with the port)? Also tell us what is the complete address of your webserver (as in what you are seeing in the browser's address bar?)

Comment: 'TEST Server' Environment : Geoserver Port-8282 Webserver port-8181.                                                'LIVE Server' Environment : Geoserver Port-8585;      Webserver Port-8181.

Comment: TEST Server Environment - http://10.50.110.11:8181/geoserver/***.php Live Server Environment - http://10.40.48.22:8181/geoserver/****.php

Comment: Since your port numbers of the webserver and geoserver  are different, you will require a proxy. if you have set up a proxy, can you check if your proxy is properly configured and working for the geoserver url in your Live environment?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe..thanks...but I think I need some help in setting up a proxy...the resource at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19613/help-setting-up-geoserver-proxy-with-openlayers is not very helpful to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I changed the 'Ip address' of 'Live Server' with its server name....
in WMS popup function & also in all related wms url paths in my map program file..

The corrected url now become - "http://[servername]:8181/geoserver/***.php"

It worked fine...

Thanks to all for your prompt effort...